# Google spreadsheets RE2 / RegEx - return all alpha words in string

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

I'm trying to extract alpha sequences in strings in Google spreadsheets.

My sequences are like `75% Cotton, 15% Organic wool, 10% Polyurethane`. My desired output would be `Cotton, Organic wool, Polyurethane`

I tried `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "([a-zA-Z ]+),")` which gives me only the first occurrence `Cotton`. This seems to be a known limitation. Is there another chance to get the desired result?

Comment: Do you want these in a single cell? Or do these have to spill? Could you add a screenshot how you see your results?

Comment: One cell. Accepted a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match 1+ digits preceded by a word boundary `\b[0-9]+` followed by `%` and a space and replace that with an empty string.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\b\d+% ", "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[0-9%]", ))
```

[image: 0]